# App crash with java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, exception, illegalstateexception

App is crashing in few devices with IllegalStateException errror. Following are the crash reports from Play console.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main
(ActivityThread.java:6776)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

**Crashed Mobile Models :**

> Samsung Galaxy J7 Max (j7maxlte) Android 7.0,
>       Galaxy J7 (j7y17lte),
>       Huawei P20 lite (HWANE), Android 8.0

What situation can lead to this crash?

Comment: The Play Console's crash logs are mostly completely useless for debugging. Firebase Crashlytics will show the actual reason for the Exception.